# CakePHP: site displays fine on local server, not on remonte

Tags: cakephp

I'm trying to understand why I have so many errors on the remote server but on local server everything's fine.

Any idea why I'm getting all of these error?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you followed these steps correctly http://ad7six.com/2007/08/24/Production-setup-revisited.html ?

Comment: I checked it out, it's to run multiple version of Cake on the same server. I don't have this problem. My links seem broken so I guess it's just a little thing to tweak and it'll be fine. I never had this problem before with Cake. I don't know what's causing it.

Answer (score 3):

looks like there's a mess with the cache files. Try disabling the cache in your remote app. 
Do this in /app/Config/core.php
Look for the following:

```
//Configure::write('Cache.disable', true);
```

and remove the // to make it works.

Best,

Comment: Thanks argamentor, now I don't see the errors anymore. However the design is completely off, the internal links won't work and when I check with Chrome inspector I can see the listed CSS files in resources but they don't open leaving me with this message: The requested URL /.. was not found on this server.

Comment: did you check if mod-rewrite is enabled in your hosting?, also you may want to check what happens if you go to:
http://yourwebsite.com/app/test.php

Comment: How do I check that in the hosting?
I checked aurelienne-brauner.net/app/test.php and I got a 404.
Whant does it mean?

Comment: Well, it should display a test page, not that error. Your problem is how you uploaded the entire website. Check the url rewrite part in the manual (specifically about how the public/app/webroot/ directory should be configured): http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/url-rewriting.html

Comment: I just tried something else. I uploaded the website to another remote server and to my surprise everything was fine! I knew from the beginning this server was trouble. I'm gonna contact the customer service, they've got to fix it as it's working perfectly fine in the other server.

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, I have no idea what generated these issues but after changing to a new hosting the issues disappeared. Always check online for hosting reviews to make sure it's a good one or you'll end up with some odd things happening on your website. Thanks y'all for your help and time.